# Xcode 7.3 Source control issue for files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, svn, version-control

I've pushed code on local server manually. Thereafter taken checkout of project using CornerStone.

However, **the project contains few file with different versioning states i.e A, M and A+.**

[image: Screenshot 1]

But project in **CornerStone dosen't shows any of these versioning states.**

[image: Screenshot 2]

I tried to fix it by committing files (showed commit success) but it remained same.

I'm worried since this **will create confusion** at later stage.

How to fix this?

Comment: its related to local git not in corner store , corner stone will show the log and modification

Comment: The project creates a hidden file ".git" with copy of your work. And all the information about git is in stored that file. There isn't anything to worry about.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : The worry part is that if I make changes in few file then I need to remember in which file changes are done. There isn't any fix?

Comment: sure you can find , but where u need this in Xcode or cornerStone

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Its fine there is no issue in CornerStone. I want to fix it in Xcode